# Get count and grouping of foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this product_user table which has foreign key product in it.

[image]

I need to group and count all of the products from that table with the same IDs and get that product name so result of the query could be:

```
+------------+--------------+-------+
| product id | product name | count |
+------------+----------------------+
| 36         | product 1    |   5   |       
+------------+----------------------+
| 22         | product 2    |   8   | 
+------------+--------------+-------+
```

I think I could use join table and one of many tries was:

```
select products.id - count(products.id)
from products
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_user ON product_user.product = products.id
group by products.Id
```

I am new at writing SQL queries so any hint can be useful.

Comment: ids are unique in the example provided. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
select products.id - count(products.id)
```

Should be:

```
select products.id, products.name, count(product_user.id)
```

Optionally change this:

```
group by products.id
```

To this:

```
group by products.id, products.name
```

Comment: And this: `group by products.Id`, should probably  be `group by products.Id, products.name`. Although not strictly necessary according to the SQL Standard, (and MySQL as long as `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is not enabled), it is a good practice to get into if you are new to SQL, and are not yet fully up to speed with the nuances of when you should, and when you shouldn't `SELECT` columns that are not included in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @GarethD if `products.Id` is primary key then specifying `products.name` is optional (it is considered functional dependent), even with recommended MySQL settings.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, I am aware of that (which is why I said *"Although not strictly necessary according to the SQL Standard"*), the point is that I see so many questions around MySQL where someone who does not fully understand what is, and is not functionally dependant misuses this extension. It was not a criticism of your answer, I just thought, given that the OP has said "I am new at writing SQL queries" that including the additional column in the group by, would be simpler than explaining functional dependency.